# Deploying JavaFX app with jlink plugin from Maven. How to get the .jar?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, launch4j, jlink

I managed to deploy my application using jlink plugin from maven. It created a sh file that works, but i would like to wrap it in one .exe file. Ive been trying do this all day but i failed. This can be done in launch4j but it needs a jar file, that jlink does not produce.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: If you're using Java 14 check out [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) (currently incubating).

Comment: I looked into it, but cant find any decent tutorial on it to understand what should i do

Comment: Here is a tutorial which I did together with Dirk Lemmermann https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX